# A question from Quantum Scattering theory Sakurai

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

This is a question from scattering theory - solution for incoming plane wave and outgoing scattered wave:

In Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics, I encountered the following line:

> Furthermore, because of angular momentum conservation, this must hold for each partial wave separately. In other words, the coefficients of $e^{ikr}/r$ must be same in magnitude as the coefficient of $e^{-ikr}/r$.

Why is that? In particular, how does it mathematically follow from $\int_S \textbf{j}\cdot d\textbf{S}=0$?

Comment: What part is not clear? Partial waves it is clear isn't it? If you decompose your plane wave into partial waves (this is what you do, isn't it?), then you can/should obey the conservation law. Do I follow the question?

Comment: @jaromrax How do you think does the conservation of angular momentum lead to the coefficients of $e^{+ikr}/r$ and $e^{-ikr}/r$ to be equal?

Comment: tell me if my answer responds to your question...may i didnt get the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you speak about elastic scattering of a plane wave on a potential.

First point is that you must follow the conservation laws. Energy and momentum, it is obvious. We know that angular momentum is also conserved, but here it is used for a trick.

The plane wave has actually all angular momenta. So you decompose PW to the sum of partial waves by $L$. Since your system is elastic scattering (no source, no sink), you should have $\int_S j \cdot dS = 0$. That means - what comes IN ($e^{-ikr}/r$) it should also go OUT ($e^{ikr}/r$). And it should work partial wave by partial wave... no way to change $L$ in the isolated system. And from here you get rules for the coefficients - the same magnitudes, so that the square of the coefficients are the same.

Comment: A $l=0$ partial wave will remain a $l=0$ partial wave after scattering?

Comment: Exactly. Think in terms of an impact factor - to change $L$ you would need to change an impact factor. You can, but with some external input.